# Syntax error in python; unexpected indent

Tags: python, syntax-error

The aim of this code is to grade the score which is between 0.0 and 1.0. below 0.6 is F, >= 0.6 is D, >= 0.7 is C, >= 0.8 is B and >= 0.9 is A; and I'm getting an error.

```
inp = raw_input ('Enter score between 0.0 & 1.0 here: ')
if inp == > 0.9:
 print A 
elif inp == > 0.8:
 print B 
elif inp == > 0.7:
 print C
elif inp == >0.6:
 print D 
else inp < 0.6:
 print F
```

Comment: In your code you have '== >'  several times : what is that? Do you mean '>=' ?

Comment: yes. By '== >' i mean '>= '. am i doing it wrong...??

Comment: Yes, you are doing it wrong. Where did you get the idea to do `== >`? Also, you'll need to change `inp` into a `float` and actually print strings like `'A'` instead of unknown variables like `A`. That said, your current code's indentation appears correct.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 idk... was doing kinda hit and try on this one... first days of coding here.. about float thing... can you elaborate it..?? Also i too noticed that i had to make A into strings to make it work.. thank you anyways

Comment: As @TigerhawkT3 mentions in a comment in one of the answers, it would be very helpful for yourself if you look through some basic Python documentation and/or tutorials for the appropriate syntax. [Official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial).

Comment: For programming, I recommend learning how to do it (from a course, book, tutorial, etc.) before you start coding, as collecting snippets of code and gluing them together without understanding them doesn't really work at all (I've tried it without success).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inp = float(raw_input('Enter score between 0.0 & 1.0 here: '))  ## This line takes the raw input in from command prompt. float('') casts the raw_input string to a float type number. 
if inp >= 0.9:
    print "A"     
elif inp >= 0.8:
    print "B" 
elif inp >= 0.7:
    print "C"
elif inp >=0.6:
    print "D" 
else:
    print "F"
```

Rewrite your code as above. You don't need to have a logical statement for "else" and you don't have 2 equal signs for greater than or equals. Also, remember to convert your string input to integer.

Use "input" instead of raw_input if your on python version 3 or higher.

```
inp = float(input ('Enter score between 0.0 & 1.0 here: '))
```

Comment: still didnt work. got the error "syntax error: invalid syntax (score.py, line 2)

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to switch the => to >= to sign. Try this above.

Comment: What version of python are you using?. raw_input is not correct if you are using version 3 or higher. The other thing you could try, is to completely start a new python file.

Comment: oooooooh!!! it worked!!! thanks a billion!!! If u have time, can you please explain the above code...?? especially the first line with float..??

Comment: Yeah, please remember to vote my question up and mark it as the correct answer. I'll comment the code lines in an edit post.

Comment: For more information on basic functions and tasks, I suggest reading the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial).

Comment: Yes. I would agree with tiger.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 hmm.. i'll do that! thank you all for the time... have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

Python knows where to end functions using indents/spaces.
For example,

```
if(1 == 1):
    print "I indented here"
```

The code below causes an error because Python sees nothing is in the if statement

```
 if(1 == 1):
 print "I indented here"
```

Comment: sorry but i m getting another error now. if you read the code, please tell me what is wrong. the error says... " syntax error: invalid syntax (score.py, line 2) "

Comment: Could you post your code again or edit the existing code?